# A question about positive elements in $C^*$ algebras

Tags: banach-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra If $a\in A$ is positive, is it true that for any $0<\alpha<\frac{1}{2}$ we have

$$\left(a+\frac{1}{n}1\right)^{\frac{-1}{2}}a^{\frac{1}{2}-\alpha}$$is self adjoint?
A more general question, is it true that if $a$ is positive then $a^\alpha$ and $\alpha>0$ is poistive? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, $a$ is positive if it is self-adjoint with spectrum in $[0,+\infty)$. The function 
$$
f(t)=\left(t+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-1/2}t^{1/2-\alpha}
$$
is continuous on $[0,+\infty)$. By continuous functional calculus, $f(a)$ is well-defined. Since $f$ is real-valued, $f(a)^*=\bar{f}(a^*)=f(a^*)=f(a)$ is self-adjoint. Moreover, the spectrum of $f(a)$ is in $f([0,+\infty))\subseteq [0,+\infty)$. So $f(a)$ is positive.

Yes to your other question for similar reasons: the function $g(t)=t^\alpha$ is continuous on $[0,+\infty)$ and takes values in $[0,+\infty)$. So $g(a)$ is positive for every positive $a$.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer

Comment: Can I ask you another question, does $a^{\frac{1}{2}-\alpha}(a+\frac{1}{n}1)^{\frac{-1}{2}}$ commute?

Comment: @ValAnderson Yes, every element $f(a)$ constructed by the continuous functional calculus of $a$ commutes with $a$.

Comment: My be I was not clear I mean is the following true $a^{\frac{1}{2}-\alpha}(a+\frac{1}{n}1)^{\frac{-1}{2}}=(a+\frac{1}{n}1)^{\frac{-1}{2}}a^{\frac{1}{2}-\alpha}$

Comment: @ValAnderson Yes, that's also true. Every element $f(a)$ belongs to the bicommutant of $a$: i.e. commutes with everything that commutes with $a$.